# Schedule file proxy to read files at a particular time in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, vfs

I need a proxy to be scheduled to start reading files from a folder at only a particular time everyday.
But i do have this vfs property set in the proxy as I'm expecting multiple files :-

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval">60000</parameter>
```

The scheduled task code is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="Test_Scheduler" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <trigger cron="0 0 7 * * ?"/>
    <property name="injectTo" value="proxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="proxyName" value="TestProxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
        <request xmlns="">
            <operation>Job Scheduler</operation>
        </request>
    </property>
</task>
```

Right now even if the scheduler is set, the file gets read after the time interval set in the vfs properties.
Is there a way i can achieve this schedule for file read?

Answer (score 0):

In the Proxy use the [File Connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector) instead of creating a `Listener Proxy` and have it triggered by the Task.